# Qt4 on Symbian: QSymbianLeaveException(KErrAlreadyExists) in (all) applications with text rendering

Tags: c++, qt4, symbian, s60

Hello and good day to you.

Recently I decided to try building C++/Qt4 applications for symbian platform (S60 r3), however I got a few problems I'm not sure how to fix.

**Problems**:

1. Any application (with child widgets such as `QLabel` or `QPushButton`) I try to compile quits immediately when launched on a cellphone. There are no error messages of any kind, but debugging has shown that at some point program throws QSymbianLeaveException with error code KErrAlreadyExists. Everything works fine in simulator or if widgets are hidden with `hide()` methods. Qt SDK examples compile but do not run on cellphone. Empty QWidget can still be displayed.
2. Any attempt to render text on `QWidget` using `QPainter::drawText()`causes program to "quit" in similar fashion(QSymbianLeaveException with error code KErrAlreadyExists (-11)). That could be the problem that causes #1. I can still paint lines/circles using `QPainter`;

**Software/Hardware setup:**
Cellphone: Nokia C5-00 (Symbian S60 r3 FP2, AFAIK)
Cellphone Qt Libraries version: 4.6.3
Firmware:  071.005 (04-Jun-2011)
PC OS: WinXP SP3
QtCreator version: 2.0.1
Application TRK version: 3.1.2
TRK API version: 3.5

**Example**:
Following code compiles and works fine in simulator, but not on the cellphone:

project file:

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = QtSymTest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY = 

symbian {
    TARGET.UID3 = 0xe6e84812
    # TARGET.CAPABILITY += 
    TARGET.EPOCSTACKSIZE = 0x14000
    TARGET.EPOCHEAPSIZE = 0x020000 0x800000
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
#if defined(Q_WS_S60)
        w.showMaximized();//application "quits" here
#else
        w.show();
#endif
        return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent){
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QPushButton* closeButton = new QPushButton(tr("C&lose"));
    layout->addWidget(closeButton);
    connect(closeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
    setLayout(layout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){                 
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtGui/QWidget>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Application output:**

```
Executable file: 7185 2011-08-29T20:28:12 D:\development\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\release\gcce\udeb\QtSymTest.exe
Package: 7632 2011-08-29T20:31:44 D:\development\projects\QtSymTest\QtSymTest.sis
Deploying application to 'Nokia C5-00 USB Serial Port (COM6)'...
Copying installation file...
Installing application...
Starting application...
Application running with pid 4958.
Finished.
```

**Debugging results:**

1. According to my debugging results, application throws QSymbianLeaveException at the `w.showMaximized()`. There are no error messages. If I comment out those lines:

   ```
   QPushButton* closeButton = new QPushButton(tr("C&lose"));
   layout->addWidget(closeButton);`
   ```

   Program will run on cellphone and I'll get empty screen with "Exit" button.
2. Application also *works if I hide the button* using `closeButton->hide()`, so apparently the problem is somehow related to displaying widgets.
3. If I add `paintEvent()` to `MainWindow` it will work, as long as I don't try to display any text. A call to drawText() will cause application to throw QSymbianLeaveException(KErrAlreadyExists) immediately:

   ```
   void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){
       QPainter painter(this);
       painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
       painter.setPen(Qt::red);
       int x1 = rect().left(), x2 = rect().right(), y1 = rect().top(), y2 = rect().bottom();
       painter.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
       painter.drawLine(x2, y1, x1, y2);
       int step = 10;
       painter.setPen(Qt::green);
       for (int x = 0; x < x2; x += 10)
           painter.drawLine(x, y1, x, y2);

       for (int y = 0; y < y2; y+= 10)
           painter.drawLine(x1, y, x2, y);

       painter.setPen(Qt::yellow);
       painter.drawEllipse(rect().center(), rect().width()/4, rect().height()/4);

       painter.drawText(rect().center(), QString("Test"));//exception is thrown here

       painter.end();
   }
   ```
4. Trying to construct QFontDatabase also causes application to throw same error.

**Additional info**:

Error code (KErrAlreadyExists) were extracted like this:

```
void processError(const std::exception& e){
    int errCode = qt_symbian_exception2Error(e);
    QString str = QString("%1: %2 , %3").arg(e.what()).arg(errCode).arg(intSize);
    QString name = typeid(e).name();
    qDebug() << e.what();//nothing gets printed in debugger at this point
    qDebug() << typeid(e).name();//but I can see values of str/name in watch window
}

...

    try{
        painter.drawText(30, 30, "Test");//application quits here
    }
    catch(std::exception &e){
        processError(e);
    }
```

So, what is the cause of this problem and how do I fix it? I finally managed to make some sense out of this problem (at least now I have error code), but I can't walk through Qt implementation in debugger so I'm not sure what exactly sure what exactly causes that problem. Ideas?

Comment: @Goz: 0x612610. It is initialized.

Comment: Hmm m... that ruins that thought.  Does it work if you just comment out the layout line?  If so then you have a memory overwrite occurring and you are getting an error in the new would be my guess.

Comment: Seeing as you can breakpoint in the constructor (i assume to get the memory address) what exactly is the line of code it aborts on?

Comment: @Goz: As I already said, it is `w.showMaximized()`. At this point debugging stops and program "finishes" with no error messages. I can't "step into" that routine. If I don't create any widget, everything "works".

Comment: Yeah sorry being a bit of a retard ...

Comment: What if you use QMainWidget instead of QWidget as you base class? Also, what if you comment out everything in the constructor so you're just displaying an empty widget?

Comment: @Kaleb Pederson: Empty widget works, as I already said ("if I comment out those lines..."). Changing base class to QMainWindow doesn't fix the issue. Apparently application quits if it tries to display a widget. If I hide the button (`closeButton->hide()`), it works.

Comment: Everything you've done seems sane, so it sounds like a bad install of the Qt libraries. A recompile/reinstall of Qt may help.

Comment: @Kaleb Pederson: Reinstalled everything (Qt SDK on Pc and Qt libraries on cellphone) and it didn't fix the problem - cellphone program terminates when trying to display button/label or rendering text. My Qt SDK has been downloaded fron nokia's website, it is precompiled, so how could that be a "bad install" anyway?

Comment: Have you managed to get working any SDK examples? Maybe your phone has some incompatible Qt libraries installed?

Comment: @Riho: "Colliding mice" example works fine (because it doesn't display any text), plus I already wrote that I can display widget and paint on top of it if there's no text. It is unlikely that the phone is incompatible with Qt 4.

Comment: Okay. Great. I figured it out.

Comment: I meant any standard sample that would use these text Widgets. If you can access http://apu.ndhub.net then you can also test it on different devices

Comment: @Riho: I figured out the problem and fixed it. See my answer.

Comment: @SigTerm - Good job tracking that one down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I had installed a custom font (overriding system default font) onto memory card and completely forgot about it, and there [are](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com//browse/QTBUG-16514) [multiple](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-19842) [problems](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com//browse/QTBUG-6611) associated with fonts and custom fonts in Qt 4.6.2 on symbian. Removed custom font and rebooted the phone, now everything works fine. As I suspected, it was a configuration problem.